# Pegar checked de campo input genérico com jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

Estou com uma dificuldade para pegar o valor dos checkbox marcados através do jQuery após um submit. Acontece que os campos inputs checkbox são gerados dinamicamente por uma consulta do banco, e não tô sabendo pegar eles de forma genérica. Exemplo do código PHP:

```
 foreach($items as $i){
   echo "<input type='checkbox' id='termo'>".$i['nome']."<br/>";
 }
```

Jquery

```
$("#buttonSubmit").on('click', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  $('#termo').get(0);
});
```

Como pegar os checkbox marcados de vários campos input com o mesmo id?

Comment: normalmente o javascript pega somente um elemento por id, se você quer que ele execute uma ação com varios inputs deveria dar a mesma classe não o mesmo id.

Comment: Não seria mais fácil pegar pelo "name" do checkbox? O Id geralmente tende a ser único por elemento html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro que repetir id's já é errado. Existem inúmeras formas de de selecionar os checkboxes. A mais comum é por uma `class`. O código abaixo retorna um *nodelist* com todos os checkbox com a classe `.nomes`:

```js
$("#buttonSubmit").on('click', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log($('input.nomes'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="nomes" type='checkbox' value='nome1'>Nome 1<br/>
<input class="nomes" type='checkbox' value='nome2'>Nome 2<br/>
<input class="nomes" type='checkbox' value='nome3'>Nome 3<br/>
<button id="buttonSubmit">OK</button>
```

O código abaixo retorna apenas os checboxes checados:

```js
$("#buttonSubmit").on('click', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log($('input.nomes:checked'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="nomes" type='checkbox' value='nome1' checked>Nome 1<br/>
<input class="nomes" type='checkbox' value='nome2'>Nome 2<br/>
<input class="nomes" type='checkbox' value='nome3'>Nome 3<br/>
<button id="buttonSubmit">OK</button>
```

Comment: Obrigado Sam, ajudou muito...